# Calling functions from plain text descriptions

Tags: artificial-intelligence, machine-learning

I have an app which has common maths functions behind the scenes:

- add(x, y)
- multiply(x, y)
- square(x)

The interface is a simple google- style text field. I want the user to be able to enter a plain text description -

- '2*3'
- '2 times 3'
- 'multiply 2 and 3'
- 'take the product of 2 and 3'

and get a answer mathematical answer

Question is, how should I map the text descriptions to the functions ? I'm guessing I need to

- tokenise the text
- identify key tokens (function names, arguments)
- try and map token combinations to function signatures

However I'm guessing this is already a 'solved problem' in the machine learning space. Should I be using Natural Language Processing ? Plain text search ? Something else ?

All ideas gratefully received, plus implementation suggestions [I'm using Python/AppEngine; I know about NLTK and Whoosh]

[PS I understand Google does this already, at least for the first two queries on the list. I'm guessing they also go it statistically, having a very large amount of search data. I don't have a large amount of data available, so will need an alternative approach].

Comment: Some questions - How many operations is it legal to write in one sentence ? (For example - will this be legal to ask - "take the product of 2 and 3 and add it to the square of product of 7 and 6" ?) And if more than one - What is maximum depth of nested operations ? From the answers to these questions it will be clear - do you need full-blown syntax tree parsing or not ...

Comment: For my compound sentence above you would need to generate such [syntax tree](http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/6347/syntaxtree.png)

Answer (score 1):

After you tokenise the text, you need [parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) to get a syntax tree of your natural language phrase. Once you have this, you can map the parse tree to a mathematical expression, and then evaluate the expression. I do not think this is a solved problem. I would start with several templates, say the first two, and experiment. The larger the domain of possible descriptions, the harder the task is.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend some tool for provide grammar/patterns on text like SimpleParse for python http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-simple.html. As java programmer I would prefer GATE or graph-expression.